# Python Snap Game

Tags: python

```
__author__ = 'Toby'
error = 0 ## Sets a variable that allows a while loop to be used
while error == 0: ## While loop so that the program will keep asking until a valid entry is inputted
    try:
        number1 = float(input("please enter 1st number")) ## The first number is inputted and stored as a variable
    except ValueError: ## Error Capture so the user can try again if invalid entry is enterd
        print("Please enter a number, it can be a decimal or an integer")
        print("try again")
    else:
        break
error2 = 0
while True: ## While loop so that the program will keep asking until a valid entry is inpuuted
    try:
        number2 = float(input("please enter 2nd number")) ## Takes second number and inouts into a different vairable
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number, it can be a decimal or an integer")
        print("try again")
    else:
        break
error3 = 0
while True: ## While true means,run the loop below so that the user can input a 3rd number,and the prgram will keep asking until it is a valid entry
    try:
        number3 = float(input("please enter 3rd number"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number, it can be a decimal or an integer")
        print("try again")
    else:
        break

if number1 == number2 and number2 == number3: ## if statement to check that if all numbers are equal then an appropiate action can be carried out
    print("SNAP!")
else:
    print("Sorry your numbers dotn match. do you want to play again?")
```

My assignment was to make a python snap game, are then any better ways i could do it to gain more marks? I am doing GCSE computer science. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't know how you can "gain more marks."

Comment: Try asking on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. If your code is functional, they should be happy to give style/optimization tips.

Comment: You could start by improving your spelling. `"Sorry your numbers dotn match. do you want to play again?"` has two characters reversed and is missing a capital.

Comment: use functions ... use comparison chaining, delete unused variables(or use them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete `error`, `error2`, and `error3` as they aren't used.

Get rid of duplication. Create a function which takes a prompt `'1st'`, `'2nd'`, or `'3rd'`. Assign the return value to `number1`, `number2`, and `number3`.

Comparing floats doesn't always give equality. Create a `close` function to check they are close enough to equal.

Create a separate function to evaluate the `snap` condition. Give it doctests which can be run to verify the behaviour.

Get rid of comments. They can be useful but are often a deodorant for messy code. If you clarify with good function, variable and parameter names, the comments become redundant.

```
__author__ = 'Pete'

def main():
    number1 = prompt(nth='1st')
    number2 = prompt(nth='2nd')
    number3 = prompt(nth='3rd')

    if snap(number1, number2, number3):
        print("SNAP!")
    else:
        print("Sorry your numbers don't match. Do you want to play again?")

def prompt(nth):
    while True:
        try:
            return float(input("please enter the {nth} number".format(nth=nth))        
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number, it can be a decimal or an integer")
            print("try again")

def snap(a, b, c):
    """
    >>> snap(1, 1, 1)
    True

    >>> snap(1.0, 1, 5/5.0)
    True

    >>> snap(1, 2, 10)
    False
    """
    return close(a, b) and close(b, c)

def close(a, b):
    return abs(a - b) < 1e-6

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```